# TextView Layout 2 lines and right aligned text

Tags: android, textview

I want to achieve this layout as in screenshot: ImageView + 2 lines of Textview -> left aligned, and in the same row I want to add another textView, but at the right end of the line.
[image]

What I tried:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/book_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#468bff"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
 />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/author_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/book_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewIcon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/book_title"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/book_title"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    />
```

As you can see in the last TextView I used toRightOf, then gravity end. This causes however to position the last TextView over the 2 lines, so it is not aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be multiple . Try something like this .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dist"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/book_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#468bff"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/author_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/book_title"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewIcon" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, just tried to use  in my original posted layout android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of wrap_content on the last TextView and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icon" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:text="SOME TITLE"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:text="Subtitle"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:text="150m"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]